# OpenCV unsatisfying results when finding Homography from ORB feature detection

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Even though the ORB Feature Matching seems quite solid and i only take the 20 best matches for cv.findHomography, the resulting polyline is terrible. Note that in the results shown in the attached image, the top right image is a video stream. Therefor the variation in results matched. Is there a library that could be used to receive better results? Or am I doing any major mistakes in my code?

[image]

```
    # des1 & des2 are created with cv.ORB_create(10000, 1.2, nlevels=8, edgeThreshold=5)

    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
    matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

    good = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance:
            good.append(m)

    matches = sorted(good, key=lambda x: x.distance)
    src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches[:20]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches[:20]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    M, mask = cv.findHomography(dst_pts, src_pts, cv.RANSAC, 5.0)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

    h = src_pts.max(0)[0][1] - src_pts.min(0)[0][1]
    w = src_pts.max(0)[0][0] - src_pts.min(0)[0][0]
    pts = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, h - 1], [w - 1, h - 1], [w - 1, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    dst = cv.perspectiveTransform(pts, M)

    img3 = None
    img3 = cv.drawMatchesKnn(img1, kp1, gray, kp2, good, img3, flags=cv.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
    img3 = cv.polylines(img3, [np.int32(dst)], True, (0, 0, 255), 3, cv.LINE_AA)

    # Code for showing img3 would follow
```

Comment: 1) Are you creating `BFMatcher` object with `cv2.NORM_HAMMING` (since ORB descriptors are binary)?
2) If you visualize just `matches[0:20]` instead of all "good" matches, are they actually correct, and do they mostly correspond to points in the 'sustainable development at goals' poster? How about after applying the `mask` returned by `cv.findHomography` (i.e. does RANSAC help with filtering out outliers?)

Comment: `BFMatcher` object with `cv2.NORM_HAMMING` - yes. In `cv.drawMatchesKnn` I do actually draw good "good" matches and not `matches[0:20]`. I think it they are _mostly_ correct. Including `cv.RANSAC, 5.0` or not, does not really make a difference. With applying mask you mean `correct_matched_kp = [good[i] for i in range(len(good)) if mask[i]]` ?

Comment: Can you show only 20 good matches that you are using in findHomography?

Answer (score 1):

There could be several problems with this setup:

1. Pattern itself. It has repeated squares, so there could be matches that connect different squares on the first and on the second image. This can produce a lot of outliers so that homography can't fit in a reasonable way
2. <strike>Low image quality. The smaller image has low resolution and a bit blurry, which makes matching more difficult, so more outliers can happen</strike>. The image has higher resolution and is just displayed in small scale, so this point is not valid.
3. Feature points are located in a small region of an image and you try to project corners of the image, which are far from the points. This makes homography estimation very unstable so that uncertainties in coordinates of feature points become magnified several times. Even jitter of less than 1 pixel can result in projection errors of up to about 8 pixels. And this can be even worse, because RANSAC threshold of 5.0 can result in coordinates with lower precision.

Comment: About 1. If  80% of the points are found within the destination image, i do not understand why the frame is not drawn at that position.
About 2. the smaller image is not a low quality - just diplayed at a small scale.
This answer sadly doesnt help very much - I still award you the bounty for your efford.

Comment: 1. RANSAC uses only 4 points to generate proposals for homography transform. So it can possibly select outliers as some of base points and fit other outliers, in which case the frame will be offset from its true position. You should better check good matches from RANSAC (`matchesMask`) instead of good matches from ORB detector.

Comment: I suggest you to start from a known homography, generate synthetic matches with some noise and outliers, and then try estimate original homography with the code from your answer. This way you can find, how sensitive is this estimation depending on noise and percentage of outliers.